# Difficulty logging in to account with Python requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program that logs into my MyPanera account and returns information like what rewards I've earned and how long until my next reward is earned. However, I'm having difficulty logging in to my account with the requests library. What information is my code missing to make this login work?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = headers={
        "user-agent": "[computer data]",
        "referer": "https://www.panerabread.com/",
        }

credentials = {
        "username": "email", 
        "password": "password", 
        "agrant_type": "password"
        }

login_url = "https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/mypanera/welcome.html"
url = "https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/mypanera/dashboard.html"

with requests.Session() as c:
    c = requests.session()
    page = c.get(login_url, headers=HEADERS)
    c.post(login_url, data=credentials, headers=HEADERS)
    page = c.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify())
```

As of now the final print statement returns the "dashboard" page as if no one has logged in.

EDIT 1:
The response code of the GET request is 500.

Comment: What is the response of the POST request? If should contain an HTTP response code, some headers, and possibly a body. Are you sure it's working? Are you sure it's even the correct URL? POSTing to a .html URL is a bit unusual, though could be fine.

Comment: The response code is [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). I'm not sure where to find the response headers. I believe the url is correct, as it brings you to the login page and the form data is in the page content. Of course, I'm fairly new to requests so it's very possible I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate answer is that the URL is incorrect. You're using the URL of the html file, not anything that looks like a login URL. It may be possible to pick through the javascript on the page and reverse engineer their login flow, but they've had some data breaches lately, so maybe it would be a bad form to discuss how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds a bit complicated but thanks for telling me what the problem is, I'll look into it.